# how can i use a variable if i have her name in a NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios

i have somewhere
float USD = 1.3032;

and a function with a parameter (NSString*)currency
and currency = @"USD";

i want to do ->
float f = 100 * currency

i want to match the currency NSString to the float
@"USD"  ->  float USD

Thanx

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking but if you are trying to convert a NSString to a float the format is [@"yourstring" floatValue];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need to store the currency name and exchange rate in a NSDictionary.

For example, if you created a dictionary

```
NSDictionary *euroExchangeRates = @{
   @"USD" : @1.3032F, 
   @"CAD" : @1.36F,
   @"GBP" : @0.86F
};
```

and you wanted `f` to contain 100 Euros in USD, you could then use:

```
float f = 100.00 * [euroExchangeRates[@"USD"] floatValue];
```

Note: The example uses the new [Objective-C literal and subscripting syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: You are taking the `floatValue` of a float/number defined as `@(x.yz)`?  The expression `100.00 * euroExchangeRates[@"USD"]` is enough.

Comment: you need the call to -floatValue because @(x.yz) is a NSNumber * not a float.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking but if you are trying to convert a NSString to a float the format is

```
[@"yourstring floatValue];
```